# How to display certain row's data in a form after clicking edit? (PHP)

Tags: php, forms, edit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuS0i.png)I'm new to PHP so please don't judge :D

I'm trying to make table with edit option. No matter in which row I click "Edit" button, only data from last row of the page gets loaded. What should I do?

```
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM countries LIMIT " . $this_page_first_result . ',' . $results_per_page;
        $result = $connection-> query($sql);

        echo '<div style="text-align:center; font-weight: bold;">';
        for ($page=1; $page<=$num_of_pages; $page++){
            echo '<a href="index.php?page=' . $page . '">' . $page . '</a> ';
        }
        echo '<div><br>';

        if($result-> num_rows > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $id = $row['id'];
        $Name = $row['Name'];
        $Area = $row['Area'];
        $Population = $row["Population"];
        $Phone_code = $row["Phone_code"];
                echo "<tr><td><a href='cities.php?id={$row['id']}'>".$row['Name']."</a></td><td>". $row["Area"] ."</td><td>"
            . $row["Population"] ."</td><td>". $row["Phone_code"] ."</td><td><button id='update-button' onclick='openEdit()'>Update</button></td><td><button id='delete-button'>Delete</button></td></tr>";
            }
            print_r($row);
        }
        else{
            echo "</table><h2 style='text-align:center'>There are no countries in the database..</h2>";
        }

    $connection-> close();
    ?>
</table>  
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
<button type="button" id="close-button-edit" onclick="closeEdit()" style="display:none">Close</button>
<div id="edit_form" style="display:none; text-align:left">
    <form action="edit_country.php" method="POST" class="forms">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
        <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" required value="<?php echo $Name; ?>"></p>
        <p>Area: <input type="text" name="area" required value="<?php echo $Area; ?>"></p>
        <p>Population: <input type="text" name="population" required value="<?php echo $Population; ?>"></p>
        <p>Phone code: <input type="text" name="phone_code" required value="<?php echo $Phone_code; ?>"></p>
        <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
        </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Which one are you expecting it to update, and why?  The reason it’s updating the last one is because that’s the latest information the variables hold

Comment: I added a pic of the web. I'm expecting to update all of the countries. As you can see, even if I click on let's say "Estonia" the form fills up with "Poland's" values.

Comment: You can’t do that with just php, because php is done before a button can be clicked. To do this, you must use a client side script (JavaScript) to monitor for an onClick event and move the data into the form. If you don’t mind a page refresh, you can do it with php using a couple of steps: when you click update, send `id ` in the query string ($_GET) and use that to do your query to prefix the form when you redraw the page

Comment: @tim would you mind showing me how to move the data with JS? I'm kinda lost and my brains are melting.. :D

Comment: Sure, but I’m on my phone and not at a point where I can type it out. If you don’t mind waiting, I’ll come back to it ASAP

Comment: Do you need the ajax explanation?  It's more involved... or is the php only section sufficient?  It all got much more detailed than I intended.

Comment: @TimMorton no need for that, already solved it with your answer. Thanks, mate!

Comment: @TimMorton maybe you could check my other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58804145/sort-with-order-by-and-limit-php

Comment: When you keep things ordered as below, see how easy it is to add?

Comment: FWIW, this layout will help you eventually make the transition to OOP programming and MVC (which you should!).  The top roughly corresponds to the Controller, the middle (database calls, business logic, etc) corresponds to the Model, and the bottom to the View.  Notice how easy it is to change your html when presented this way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two strategies that can be used for this problem: all php or using JavaScript.

### PHP Only

This requires a submission to pre-fill the edit form. Each update button sends the `id` as a GET request (it is requesting information, not changing information, so use GET), in the form of an ordinary link, which the php script uses to populate the edit form.

```
<?php 
// always start with php stuff and don't issue any html until you're done

// initialization
$sortDirection = 'asc';
if(isset($_REQUEST['sortDirection'])) {
    // this decouples the value from user input.  It can only be 'Asc' or 'Desc'
    $sortDirection = $_REQUEST['sortDirection'] == 'asc' ? 'Asc' : 'desc';
}
$rowToEdit = '';
$pdo = new PDO( ... );

// Using PDO because it is more standard
// Leaving connection details to user. See https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql for tutorial 
// $pdo is assumed to be the pdo object

// deal with row delete. Destructive, so will be post, and delete button will be set
if(isset ($_POST['delete']) ) {

    // delete from countries where id = ?

    //redirect back to self (Post, Redirect, Get pattern). 
    // Always do this when done working with POST submissions!

    header('Location: /countries.php');
    exit;
}

// deal with row update. This changes data, so use POST
if(isset($_POST['id'])) {

    // update countries set ...

    // redirect back to self
    header('Location: /countries.php');
    exit;
}

// deal with request for row to edit, use GET for info requests 
if(array_key_exists('id', $_GET) {

    $rowToEdit = $pdo->prepare("select * from countries where id = ?");
    $rowToEdit->execute([$id]);
    // fall through to show page
}
// get all country rows (Note, OK to use $sortDirection here because it is decoupled from user input)
$country = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM countries ORDER BY NAME $sortDirection")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);

// got all our data, dealt with user input, now we can present the view
?>
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Countries</h1>
    <a href="/countries.php?sortDirection=asc">Sort Asc</a>
    <a href="/countries.php?sortDirection=desc">Sort Desc</a>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
         <th>Area</th>
         <th>Population</th>
         <th>Phone</th>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
      </tr>
      <?php foreach( $country as $row): ?>
      <tr>
        <td><a href='cities.php?country_id=<?=$row['id']?>'><?=$row['Name']?></a></td>
        <td><?=$row["Area"]?></td>
        <td><?=$row["Population"]?></td>
        <td><?=$row["Phone_code"]?></td>
        <td> <a href='countries.php?id=<?=$row['id']?>'>Update</a> </td>
        <td>
          <form method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$row['id']?>" />
          <button id='delete-button'>Delete</button>
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <?php if($rowToEdit): ?>

    <div style="text-align:center">
        <form action="countries.php" method="POST" class="forms">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= rowToEdit ['id']?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="sortDirection" value="<?= $sortDirection?>">
          <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" required value="<?= $rowToEdit['Name']?>"></p>
          <p>Area: <input type="text" name="area" required value="<?= $rowToEdit['Area']?>"></p>
          <p>Population: <input type="text" name="population" required value="<?= $rowToEdit["Population"]?>"></p>
          <p>Phone code: <input type="text" name="phone_code" required value="<?= $rowToEdit["Phone_code"]?>"></p>
          <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
        </form>
    </div>

    <?php endif; ?>

  </body>
</html>
```