# PHP MySQL Comment System With Replies

Tags: php, comments, system, reply

I have code that is able to capture the initial comment and the 1st level of replies, but it doesn't seem to capture the reply to a reply. I know that it requires an indefinite code using some form of recursion, but not quite sure how to properly implement it. 
Here's what my phpMyAdmin table looks like:

id  name    comment reply_id
1   BigBadProducer1 I love this vst! I use it all the time! 0
2   DrummaBoy504    Hey, this is Drumma from Drum Squad!    0
3   Mike Smith  How did you get the vst to sound so good like that...   1
4   BigBadProducer1 Yes, I learned how to tweak it from YouTube Mike S...   3
5   SmoothBeatz3    Dude, Ive been looking for a vst like this for a l...   0
6   FanBoy123   Hey Drumma, when are you going to release a new hi...   2
7   Mike Johnson    Hey Fanboy123, why are you such a fanboy of Drum S...   6

Here's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'mypassword', 'commentsystem2');

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE reply_id = 0";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);

while ($comment = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $id = $comment['id'];
    $name = $comment['name'];
    $comment = $comment['comment'];
    
echo '
<div class="comments" style="position:relative; margin:auto; width:500px; border:1px solid black; margin-top:1px;">
<div>'.$name.'</div>
<div>'.$comment.'<br><br></div>
</div>
';

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE reply_id = $id";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
while ($reply = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
$id_reply = $reply['id'];
$reply_name = $reply['name'];
$reply_comment = $reply['comment'];
$reply_id = $reply['reply_id'];


echo '
<div class="replies" style="position:relative; margin:auto; width:500px; border:1px solid black; margin-top:1px;">
<div style="width:80%; text-align:center;">'.$reply_name.' replied to '.$name.'</div>
<div style="width:80%; text-align:center;">'.$reply_comment.'<br><br></div>
</div>
';

 }//end of replies while loop

}//end of comments while loop

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A few foundational thoughts: recursion is not the only way to do it. Check out “materialized path”: you’d have to redo the reply_id, but the benefits might well be worth it. If you do choose to go forward with recursion, you’ll need to take steps toward a more sophisticated style of coding. Currently, you are using a very procedural style: deal with things as they occur in the presentation of the page. You’ll need to adopt more of an OOP style; at the least you’ll need a function that calls itself.  I would suggest using the style in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58806465/2129574

Comment: When you get the logic at the top and the presentation at the bottom, then it’s easier to incorporate the function to do recursion.

Comment: Thanks for the concepts Tim. Do you have an example or code snippet I can test? I need to keep it inside of the database though, but I'm open to trying your ideas. THanks again.

Answer (score 0):

### Recursion

Here is a quick example of the recursive solution, using arrays as a mockup of database queries.

Some important notes:

1. Note the structure: All data fetching and manipulation is done before a single thing is printed out.
2. This would be far better as an object, which would avoid the `GLOBAL` tags inside the functions, but this gets you pointed in that direction.
3. Recursive functions should always have a test to stop recursion in case something goes awry.  This example does not!  You could use a static variable to count recursions and stop if some limit is reached.

---

```
<?php

// mock data of "select * from comments"
$dbRows = [
  1 => ['name' => 'BigBadProducer1', 'comment' => 'I love this vst! I use it all the time!', 'reply_id' => 0],
  2 => ['name' => 'DrummaBoy504', 'comment' => 'Hey, this is Drumma from Drum Squad!', 'reply_id' => 0],
  3 => ['name' => 'Mike Smith', 'comment' => 'How did you get the vst to sound so good like that...', 'reply_id' => 1],
  4 => ['name' => 'BigBadProducer1', 'comment' => 'Yes, I learned how to tweak it from YouTube Mike S...', 'reply_id' => 3],
  5 => ['name' => 'SmoothBeatz3', 'comment' => 'Dude, Ive been looking for a vst like this for a l...', 'reply_id' => 0],
  6 => ['name' => 'FanBoy123', 'comment' => 'Hey Drumma, when are you going to release a new hi...', 'reply_id' => 2],
  7 => ['name' => 'Mike Johnson', 'comment' => 'Hey Fanboy123, why are you such a fanboy of Drum S...', 'reply_id' => 6],
  ];

// mock data of "select id from comments where reply_id=?"
$children = [];
foreach($dbRows as $id => $row) {
  $reply_id = $row['reply_id'];
  $children[$reply_id][] = $id;
}

// format row into html
function formatRow($row, $reply_name='unknown') {
    $out =<<<FORMATROW
<div class="replies" style="position:relative; margin:auto; width:500px; border:1px solid black; margin-top:1px;">
<div style="width:80%; text-align:center;">{$row['name']} replied to {$reply_name}</div>
<div style="width:80%; text-align:center;">{$row['comment']}<br><br></div>
</div>
FORMATROW;

    return $out;
}

// mock of database CRUD function "select * from comments where id=?"
function find($id) {
    global $dbRows;
    if(array_key_exists($id, $dbRows)) {
        return $dbRows[$id];
    }
}

// mock of database CRUD function "select id from comments where reply_id=?"
function findChildren($id) {
    global $children;
    if($id == 0) { return []; }

    $out = [];
    if(array_key_exists($id, $children)) {

        $out = $children[$id];
    }
    return $out;
}

function getRepliesTo($id) {

    // test to end recursion
    // if(!$id) { return; }

    // get parent name
    $row = find($id);
    $parent_name = $row['name'];

    // start indented list every time a traversal is called
    $out = "<ul>\n";

    // list of child ids. if no children are found, 
    // assigns an empty array so that foreach won't barf
    $children = findChildren($id);

    foreach($children as $cid) {

        // if there are children, capture their reply and then call this same function to get replies to this reply            
        if($reply= find($cid)) {
            $out .= '  <li>' . formatRow($reply, $parent_name);
            $out .= getRepliesTo($cid);
            $out .= "</li>\n";
        }
    }

    $out .= "</ul>\n";
    return $out;
}

// print_r(find(1));
// print_r(findChildren(1));
// print_r(findChildren(2));
// print traverse(1);

$id = 1; // $id = (int)$_GET['id'];

$commentData = find($id);
$replyHtml = getRepliesTo($id);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="comments" style="position:relative; margin:auto; width:500px; border:1px solid black; margin-top:1px;">
    <div><?= $commentData['name'] ?></div>
    <div><?= $commentData['comment'] ?><br><br></div>
  </div>
  <?= replyHtml ?>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### Materialized Path

Another method would be to use Materialized Path query, which would require a slight change to the reply_id field:

```
$dbRows = [
  1 => ['name' => 'BigBadProducer1', 'comment' => 'I love this vst! I use it all the time!',               'reply_id' => '/0/1'],
  2 => ['name' => 'DrummaBoy504',    'comment' => 'Hey, this is Drumma from Drum Squad!',                  'reply_id' => '/0/2'],
  3 => ['name' => 'Mike Smith',      'comment' => 'How did you get the vst to sound so good like that...', 'reply_id' => '/0/1/3'],
  4 => ['name' => 'BigBadProducer1', 'comment' => 'Yes, I learned how to tweak it from YouTube Mike S...', 'reply_id' => '/0/1/3/4'],
  5 => ['name' => 'SmoothBeatz3',    'comment' => 'Dude, Ive been looking for a vst like this for a l...', 'reply_id' => '/0/5'],
  6 => ['name' => 'FanBoy123',       'comment' => 'Hey Drumma, when are you going to release a new hi...', 'reply_id' => '/0/2/6'],
  7 => ['name' => 'Mike Johnson',    'comment' => 'Hey Fanboy123, why are you such a fanboy of Drum S...', 'reply_id' => '/0/2/6/7'],
  ];
```

Want to find all descendants of 2?  `select * from comments where reply_id like '/0/2%'`