# Redirect a PHP file to another PHP file AFTER all required fields are answered correctly

Tags: php, html, forms

Im new to coding and I really need help. I have a PHP form that I want to redirect to another PHP file after hitting submit and all the required fields are answered correctly. The redirecting is not working without jeopardizing the form file. Sorry for dumb question but please help and If you could also tell me where to put the code, I've tried:

```php
< ?php header("Location: http://www.redirect.to.url.com/"); ?>
```

but then It redirects immediately as you enter the form page.

Comment: Please post the rest of your code.

Comment: Please post your code here, so we can help

Comment: You redirect when you have a user submission: that means you need to check the $_POST or $_GET variable for content.  See an example of this at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58806465/2129574

Answer (score -2):

you can use onsubmit Event it makes you able to submit the inputs or not, check this code:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return myFunction()">
Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
//your code or process
return true; //if fields are answered
return false; //if fields are notanswered 
 }
</script>
```

I didn't understand you well what yo  mean by fields must be are answered.You mean correct or not empty? if not empty u can use required attribute

```
<form  action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return myFunction()">
Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

if not you can check if fileds correct by checjing them by js and don't forget to return true so the php file can run.
Hope this help if not post your code